# PHP forward_static_call_array in a non-static class context

Tags: php, arguments, forwarding

Good day,

I have the following testcase that I cannot get to work properly.

```
<?php

class TestClass{
private $obj                =   NULL;



public function __construct(){
    $this->obj = new SubClass();    
}



public function test(){
    forward_static_call_array('SubClass::callMe', func_get_args());
}
}


class SubClass{
    public function callMe(){
        echo 'YES WE FETCHED : '.PHP_EOL.print_r(func_get_args(), true);
    }
}



$test = new TestClass();
$test->test('John', 'Doe', array('Peter', 'Dora'), array('Anthony', 'William'));
?>
```

As you see I have two classes.

## 1 TestClass

This is a non static class that is beeing called by:

```
$test = new TestClass();
$test->test('John', 'Doe', array('Peter', 'Dora'), array('Anthony', 'William'));
```

Within the *TestClass()* I load with a constructor a new class inside the parent class.

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->obj = new SubClass();    
}
```

Then I load a class method called *test()* with the following line:

```
$test->test('John', 'Doe', array('Peter', 'Dora'), array('Anthony', 'William'));
```

This method then fetches the function arguments with : **func_get_args()**
And forwards all arguments with **forward_static_call_array()**

As following:

```
public function test(){
    forward_static_call_array('SubClass::callMe', func_get_args());
}
```

Calling it by :

- SubClass::callMe

Makes it a static class. And logically I get an error message:

**Strict standards: forward_static_call_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method SubClass::callMe() should not be called statically in N:\wamp\www\test\forward_arguments\testclass.php on line 15**

## 2 SubClass

The *subClass* fetches the arguments as following:

```
public function callMe(){
    echo 'YES WE FETCHED : '.PHP_EOL.print_r(func_get_args(), true);
}
```

Now with this setup the error notice is logic.
And the *TestClass* class variable

```
private $obj                =   NULL;
```

get's completely avoided.

```
$this->obj = new SubClass();
```

## The problem specific

The problem line is this one:

```
forward_static_call_array('SubClass::callMe', func_get_args());
```

The syntax should be different. But I have no idea how.
Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

The problem is that I do know how to call static class methods. But I do not know how to call a method in a loaded class.

## Solution

*(provided by : **Rizier123**)*

```
<?php

class TestClass{
    private $obj                =   NULL;



    public function __construct(){
        $this->obj = new SubClass();    
        $this->obj->SetExtra(array('Karel', 'Anton'));
    }



    public function test(){
        forward_static_call_array([$this->obj, 'callMe'], func_get_args());
    }
}


class SubClass{
    private $SetVar = NULL;

    public function callMe(){
        $Array = $this->ArrayStrUp(array_merge(func_get_args(), $this->SetVar));

        echo 'YES WE FETCHED : '.PHP_EOL.print_r($Array, true);
    }

    public function SetExtra($vars){
        $this->SetVar = $vars;
    }



    private function ArrayStrUp($Arr){
        foreach($Arr as $key => $value){
            if(is_array($value) === true){
                $Arr[$key] = $this->ArrayStrUp($value);
            }
            else{
                $Arr[$key] = strtoupper($value);
            }
        }

        return($Arr);
    }
}



$test = new TestClass();
$test->test('John', 'Doe', array('Peter', 'Dora'), array('Anthony', 'William'));
?>
```

Comment: What would you expect as output and what is your current output? Also you don't have any static functions in your classes!

Comment: I know. And I want to use the class variable $obj
So it should be `forward_static_call_array('$this->obj->callMe', func_get_args());`

But that doesn't work :-o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to change this:

```
forward_static_call_array('SubClass::callMe', func_get_args());
```

to:

```
forward_static_call_array([$this->obj, 'callMe'], func_get_args());
```

And you also have to declare your method static, e.g:

```
class SubClass{
    public static function callMe(){
         //^^^^^^ See here
        echo 'YES WE FETCHED : '.PHP_EOL.print_r(func_get_args(), true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks!! Added the full working code in the question. Plus I added some extra options to prove the functioning of the concept.

Comment: How are we supposed to deal with exotic cases where the class name is generated dynamically ? (ie.: the class name is a string contained in a string variable)

Comment: @FMaz008 As in the example `$this->obj` would contain the class name.